# Geting sum for main and sub-main categories from three tables in SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables in SQLite database; the first table (`PROJWBS`) describes the project works and sub-works like this:

| PROJ_ID | WBS_ID | PARENT_WWBS_ID | WBS_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | MAIN WORK |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | WORK-01 |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | WORK-02 |

The second table (`TASK`) describes the work tasks:

| TASK_ID | PROJ_ID | WBS_ID | TASK_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | Tiling |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | Metal Works |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | Wood Works |

And the third table (`TASKRSRC`) describes the tasks target cost:

| TASK_ID | PROJ_ID | TARGET_COST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |
| 1 | 1 | 750 |
| 2 | 1 | 350 |
| 3 | 1 | 150 |

I have created this query to order the first table by work & sub-works arrangement and calculate the works & sub-works cost :

```
SELECT 
    PROJWBS.Wbs_id, PROJWBS.Parent_Wbs_id, PROJWBS.Wbs_name,  
    COALESCE(subquery.Total_Cost, 0) AS Total_Cost 
FROM 
    PROJWBS 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         TASK.Wbs_id, SUM(TASKRSRC.Target_Cost) AS Total_Cost 
     FROM 
         TASK 
     JOIN 
         TASKRSRC ON TASK.Task_id = TASKRSRC.Task_id  
     GROUP BY 
         TASK.Wbs_id) AS subquery ON PROJWBS.Wbs_id = subquery.Wbs_id  
WHERE 
    PROJ_ID = 1
GROUP BY 
    PROJWBS.Wbs_id, PROJWBS.Parent_Wbs_id, PROJWBS.Wbs_name    
ORDER BY 
    CASE  
        WHEN PROJWBS.Wbs_id = PROJWBS.PARENT_WBS_ID THEN PROJWBS.PARENT_WBS_ID  
        WHEN PROJWBS.Wbs_id < PROJWBS.PARENT_WBS_ID THEN PROJWBS.WBS_ID   
        WHEN PROJWBS.Wbs_id > PROJWBS.PARENT_WBS_ID THEN PROJWBS.PARENT_WBS_ID 
    END;
```

The resulting table displays only 0 values ​​for the cost of the main works and calculates the cost only for the subworks.

Note: the main tasks have nothing to do with the task table, while the subtasks has.

The query should return a result like this (taking by consideration the order condition inside my query ):

| WBS_ID | WBS_NAME | Total_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAIN WORK | 1750 |
| 10 | WORK-01 | 1600 |
| 11 | WORK-02 | 150 |

Solution will be appreciated.

Comment: In third norm relational design, arguably `PROJ_ID` should only appear at top level table and not repeat in child tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a second aggregate subquery to sum total cost at project level:

```sql
SELECT p.WBS_ID, p.PARENT_WBS_ID, p.WBS_NAME,  
       COALESCE(main_agg.TOTAL_COST, sub_agg.TOTAL_COST, 0) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM PROJWBS p
LEFT JOIN (  
    SELECT PROJ_ID, SUM(TARGET_COST) AS TOTAL_COST 
    FROM TASKRSRC  
    GROUP BY PROJ_ID
) AS main_agg
  ON p.PROJ_ID = main_agg.PROJ_ID
  AND p.PARENT_WBS_ID = 0
LEFT JOIN (  
    SELECT TASK.WBS_ID, SUM(TASKRSRC.TARGET_COST) AS TARGET_COST 
    FROM TASK 
    JOIN TASKRSRC ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASKRSRC.TASK_ID 
    GROUP BY TASK.WBS_ID
) AS sub_agg
   ON p.WBS_ID = sub_agg.WBS_ID
WHERE p.PROJ_ID = 1
ORDER BY ... ;
```